# Android: Change image for a particular item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

[image: screen shot]

In the above image, there is a list view which contains list of items that the user can download. [image: download button] This is the image which tells user that he can download the file. On completion of download, the image will change to [image: download completed button]. My problem is when I download a file, the status image(which denotes that download has completed) gets changed for another row, instead, it should change for the row that I had selected. At present, if I download first file in the list, the image gets changed for 4th or 5th item in the list. Also, when I try to download any other file from the list. it opens up last downloaded file(This is functionality of the app that if file is already downloaded, then open it in pdf reader),i.e., if I download 1st file in the list and then go for second item,then instead of downloading 2nd file, it opens up last downloaded file. More over, if I scroll the listview, the status of download gets changed for other items in the list also. Below,is my adapter code:

```
public class DownloadListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
public ArrayList<DownloadListDao> mDownloadList;
String readMoreLink;
public static final String TAG = "DownloadListAdapter";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private boolean isSDCardPresent;
File tieDir;
int downloadState[];

public DownloadListAdapter(Context ctx,
        ArrayList<DownloadListDao> mDownloadList) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.mDownloadList = mDownloadList;
    downloadState = new int [mDownloadList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < mDownloadList.size(); i++) {
        downloadState[i] = 0;
    }
    tieDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/tie");
}// Constructor

public int getCount() {
    return this.mDownloadList.size();
}// getCount

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.mDownloadList.get(position);
}// getItem

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}// getItemId

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle, txtTheme, txtDate;
    ImageView imgDownload;
}// ViewHolder

ViewHolder holder;

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String url = mDownloadList.get(position).getUrl();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.downlist_adapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.txtTheme = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtTheme);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        holder.imgDownload = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgDload);

        holder.imgDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File mediaFile = null;
                if (url != null && !url.equals("null") && !url.equals("")) {
                    String fileName = url.toString().substring(
                            url.toString().lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            url.toString().length());
                    mediaFile = new File(tieDir, fileName);
                }
                processFile(mediaFile, url, position);
                int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
                downloadState[pos] = 1;
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (mDownloadList != null && mDownloadList.size() > 0) {
        if (mDownloadList.get(position).getTitle() != null
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getTitle().equals("null")
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getTitle().equals("")) {
            holder.txtTitle.setText(mDownloadList.get(position).getTitle());
        }

        if (mDownloadList.get(position).getTheme() != null
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getTheme().equals("null")
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getTheme().equals("")) {
            holder.txtTheme.setText(mDownloadList.get(position).getTheme());
        }

        if (mDownloadList.get(position).getDate() != null
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getDate().equals("null")
                && !mDownloadList.get(position).getDate().equals("")) {
            holder.txtDate.setText(mDownloadList.get(position).getDate());
        }

        if (downloadState[position] == 1) {
            holder.imgDownload.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_dloaded));
        } else {
            holder.imgDownload.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_dload));
        }
    }
    holder.imgDownload.setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}// getView

protected void downloadFile(String url, int position, String fileName) {

    Log.v(TAG, "Preparing to download");
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Dowloading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    isSDCardPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if (!isSDCardPresent) {
        noSDCardAlert(ctx);
    } else {
        if ((tieDir.exists()) && (tieDir != null)) {
            if (NetworkConnection.isOnline(ctx)) {
                if (tieDir.isDirectory()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "if tie dir URL:::" + url);
                    new DownloadAudioAsync(ctx, position, fileName).execute(url);
                }
            } else {
                ((DownloadListActivity) ctx)
                        .OpenNetErrDialog("Please check your internet connection...");
            }
        } else {
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = tieDir.mkdirs();
            if (isDirectoryCreated) {
                Log.v(TAG, "if tie not dir URL:::" + url);
                if (NetworkConnection.isOnline(ctx)) {
                    new DownloadAudioAsync(ctx, position, fileName).execute(url);
                } else {
                    ((DownloadListActivity) ctx)
                            .OpenWiFiDialog("Please check your internet connection...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void noSDCardAlert(Context ctx) {
    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    ad.setMessage("No sd card present..");
    ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    if (!((DownloadDetail) ctx).isFinishing()) {
        ad.show();
    }
}

public void OpenDialog(String messageID) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_base);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    TextView alertMessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    Button btnOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOK.setText("Show");
    alertMessage.setText(messageID);
    dialog.show();
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

protected void showPdf(File mediaFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mediaFile), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}

public class DownloadAudioAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Context ctx;
    int pos;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    String fileName;

    public DownloadAudioAsync(Context ctx, int pos, String fileName) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v(TAG, "inside on pre execute");
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pd.setMessage("Downloading...\nPlease wait..");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {
            Log.v(TAG,
                    "inside do in background with url::"
                            + aurl[0].toString());
            aurl[0] = aurl[0].replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);

            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF-8");
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tieDir + "/"
                    + fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        if (!((DownloadListActivity) ctx).isFinishing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
            updateView(pos);
        }
    }

    private void updateView(int pos) {
        View v = ((DownloadListActivity) ctx).menuListView.getChildAt(pos
                - ((DownloadListActivity) ctx).menuListView
                        .getFirstVisiblePosition());
        ImageView imgDloadBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDload);
        imgDloadBtn.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_dloaded));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private void processFile(File mediaFile, String url, int pos) {
    if (url != null && !url.equals("null") && !url.equals("")) {
        if (mediaFile != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "in processFile FileName " + mediaFile.getName());
            Log.v(TAG, "in processFile Position " + pos);
            if(!mediaFile.exists()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "in processFile Media file doesn't exists");
                downloadFile(url, pos, mediaFile.getName());
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "in processFile Media file exists");
                try {
                    showPdf(mediaFile);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    OpenDialog("PDF Reader is not installed on your device.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}// DownloadAdapter
```

I had read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7739006#7739006) for recycling the view(Thanks to [Knickedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920511/knickedi) for in depth explaination). But, I can't figure out where is actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue with `getview` Method which keep recreating whenever you scroll your view, to handle exact position you have to play with `setTag & getTag`,check below few stackvoerflow answers to understand `setTag & getTag`:

[Button in ListView using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154397/646806)

[Getting radio button value from custom list in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646471/646806)

and even store downloaded state into one `booleanarray`  like below:

```
int boxState[];
```

within adapter constructor, set zero initially:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getData.size(); i++) {
    boxState[i] = 0;

    }
```

within adapter getview method:

```
holder.imgDownload.setTag(position);
```

Now you click on download button set value as 1 (Inside onclick of button):

```
pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
boxState[pos]=1;
```

At last when you scroll your view check condition into following way(put below code inside getview method):

```
if (boxState[position] == 0) {
            holder.imgDownload.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_dloaded)); //which aren't downloaded
        } else {
             holder.imgDownload.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_dload)); // which are downloaded.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but now I am facing one more problem. If I click on the button of first item to download the file, it is downloading correct file. But, when I click on the same button again, in the first row, instead of opening file, it downloads the last file. What I mean to say, is at a time, six items are visible in the list. When, I click on the button in the first item, it downloads correct file, but when I click on it again, it downloads the file associated with url of 6th item in list view. I had updated my code.

Comment: Just change position of this line `holder.imgDownload.setTag(position);` keep before onclick of button and then check

Comment: pass get tag `pos` in your "if" conditions, instead passing `position`

Comment: Found the bug, it is updateView(pos) which I am calling in onPostExecute(), to change the image after download completes. As, I have to update the view, what will be the best way? I am thinking to store the reference of buttons in an arraylist or vector on the same position which I had set as tag. Is it correct way to do?

Comment: Thanks for help, its working fine now. Earlier, I was not getting idea about how to use getTag()