# ListView with Checkboxes Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

The Activity below, `ContactMailAdapter.class` is my list view adapter containing checkbox. If i want to get the position of a row that has been checked. how can this be done. I have several checkboxes in my list and I can checked multiple checkbox. My logic is that I should store each position that has been checked. then call the data from my arraylist but for now I am not able to get the position of a checked item from my adapter.

```
public class ContactMailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Destinataire> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    ViewHolder holder;
    static String src;

    PopMessage main;

    public ContactMailAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Destinataire> mArticles) {

        activity = a;
        data = mArticles;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }



    public ContactMailAdapter (PopMessage m){
                this.main=m;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.toArray().length;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView one;
        public TextView two;
        public CheckBox check;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popise_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_top);
            holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_bottom);
            holder.check = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.search_imag);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


            holder.one.setText(data.get(position).getName());
            holder.two.setText(data.get(position).getEmail());




            vi.findViewById(R.id.search_imag).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (holder.check.isChecked())
                        System.out.println("false"+v.getId());
                    else 
                        System.out.println("false");

                }
            });


            holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()                  
                     {
                      @Override
                      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                              boolean isChecked) {



                      }
                  });



        /*  vi.findViewById(R.id.search_image).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    v.findViewById(R.id.search_image).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boutton_off);
                    if (holder.check.isChecked())
                        System.out.println("true");
                    else 
                        System.out.println("false");

                }
            }); */



        return vi;
    }


}
```

**NEW UPDATE**

```
ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (ids.contains(holder.check.getId() + "")) {
                        holder.check.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        holder.check.setChecked(false);
                    }

                    holder.check
                            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {



                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                        boolean isChecked) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    int id = buttonView.getId(); 
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                        if (ids.contains(id + "")) {
                                        } else {
                                            ids.add(id + "");
                                            id++;
                                            System.out.println( "receipe" + id);

                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if (ids.contains(id + "")) {
                                            ids.remove(id + "");
                                            System.out.println( "receipe" + id);

                                          //  ids--;
                                        } else {
//                                        id = 0;
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Check my answer. Full and Final solution...

Answer (score 1):

This is how i implemented the same, but i used images instead of built-in checkboxes to check/uncheck the list item.

My listview's single row contains TextView and Imageview.

Below is the code of ArrayAdapter and listview's onItemClick() event:

```
static class Category {

        String cat_name = "";
        int cat_id = 0;
        Boolean checked = false;

        Category(int cat_id, String name) {
            this.cat_name = name;
            this.cat_id = cat_id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return cat_id;
        }

        public String getCatName() {
            return cat_name;
        }

        public Boolean getChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void toggleChecked() {
            checked = !checked;
        }
    }

    static class CategoryViewHolder {

        ImageView imageViewCheck;
        TextView textViewCategoryName;

        public CategoryViewHolder(ImageView iv_check, TextView tv_category_name) {
            imageViewCheck = iv_check;
            textViewCategoryName = tv_category_name;
        }

        public ImageView getImageViewCheck() {
            return imageViewCheck;
        }

        public TextView getTextViewCategoryName() {
            return textViewCategoryName;
        }
    }

    static class CategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList) {

            super(context, R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                    R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData, categoryList);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Category category = (Category) this.getItem(position);

            final ImageView imageViewCheck;
            final TextView textViewCN;

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_delete_data,
                        null);

                imageViewCheck = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowDeleteData);
                textViewCN = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowDeleteData);

                convertView.setTag(new CategoryViewHolder(imageViewCheck,
                        textViewCN));
            }

            else {

                CategoryViewHolder viewHolder = (CategoryViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                imageViewCheck = viewHolder.getImageViewCheck();
                textViewCN = viewHolder.getTextViewCategoryName();
            }

            imageViewCheck.setFocusable(false);
            imageViewCheck.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            imageViewCheck.setClickable(true);
            imageViewCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                    Category category = (Category) iv.getTag();

                    if (category.getChecked() == false) {
                        imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
                        listOfItemsToDelete.add(category.getId());
                        category.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        imageViewCheck
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);
                        listOfItemsToDelete.remove((Integer) category.getId());
                        category.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            imageViewCheck.setTag(category);

            if (category.getChecked() == true)
                imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
            else
                imageViewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);

            textViewCN.setText(category.getCatName());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

---

ListView's `onItemClick()` event:

```
lv_delete_data.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowDeleteData);
                Category category = (Category) imageView.getTag();

                if (category.getChecked() == false) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_check);
                    listOfItemsToDelete.add(category.getId());
                    category.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.set_basecircle);
                    listOfItemsToDelete.remove((Integer) category.getId());
                    category.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is how i implemented, the same thing which you require. If you have any query you can ask me.

Comment: i only want the positions of checked items

Comment: This is how i did in my application. In my case, i stored the rowids using set tag to the check boxes. And when checkboxes were clicked, i get their tags and from that tags i get their id that i used to store in the arraylist `listofitemstodelete`. What else do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
holder.check_favourite.setId(position);


        if (ids.contains(holder.check_favourite.getId() + "")) {
            holder.check_favourite.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.check_favourite.setChecked(false);
        }
        int id= 0;

        holder.check_favourite
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int check = buttonView.getId();
                        if (isChecked) {
                            if (ids.contains(check + "")) {
                            } else {
                                ids.add(check+ "");
                                id++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (ids.contains(check + "")) {
                                ids.remove(check + "");
                                id--;
                            } else {

                            }

                        }

                    }
                });
```

The if condition to set checkbox true or false is used so that your checkbox doesn't get unchecked when you scroll your listview...
This is my code apply the same code for your checkbox..Hope you get it...

Comment: please what is receipe_auto_id

Comment: Sorry that was from my code..You just ignore that..And put int id = buttonView.getId(); instead of recipe_auto_id into your List.

Comment: will it get the exact position of the row in the listview or just increment a number

Comment: check my new update: i tried with your answer but i get only a series of number

Comment: Obviously it will print the position of view starting from 0 to onwards..But later on we check the condition that if checkview is checked if yes then and only then it will be added into your list...

Comment: but friend i am not getting the id result 2131362026

Comment: I have update the code for better understanding..Check it..And declare List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(); outside the getView() method.

Comment: suppose i checked item at position 3 first, my id will be 1 which is wrong. if i checked position 3, id should be 3 and item 10 id should be 10 not incremented by 1 friend. i need exact id

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play around [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29). I would like to recommend you reading these posts:

[Android: Change image for a particular item in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965673/1292544) and [Getting an issue while checking the dynamically generated checkbox through list view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739006/1292544).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). This tutorial covers how to add checkboxes to listViews and handle updating and checking their status

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get or store checked item, you can use array adapter. Check out this code.It might help you out.

/**Defining checkbox click event listener**/

`OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;

        int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

        for(int i=0 ; i < itemCount ; i++){

            getListView().setItemChecked(i, chk.isChecked());
        }
    }
```

`};`

```
/**Defining click event listener for the listitem checkbox**/
```

`OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {`

```
@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);

    int checkedItemCount = getCheckedItemCount();

    if(getListView().getCount()==checkedItemCount)

        chk.setChecked(true);

    else

        chk.setChecked(false);
    }
};

/**Getting reference to checkbox available in the main.xml layout**/
```

`CheckBox chkAll =  ( CheckBox ) findViewById(R.id.chkAll);`

```
/**Setting a click listener for the checkbox**/
```

`chkAll.setOnClickListener(clickListener);`

```
/**Setting a click listener for the listitem checkbox**/

 ` getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener); `
```

`}`

/**Returns the number of checked items**/

`private int getCheckedItemCount()`
{

```
int cnt = 0;

SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){

    if(positions.get(i))

        cnt++;
}
```

`return cnt;`

}

**And to update the checked item , use**

`SparseBooleanArray checked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();`