# How to get selected radio button for each row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, radio-group

I have a list of students in a `ListView` for which I want to keep track of attendance (somewhat similar to [How to get checked radio button in list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674286/how-to-get-checked-radio-button-in-list-view) and [Listview with Checkbox,RadioButton,Textview and button not working correctly in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602426/listview-with-checkbox-radiobutton-textview-and-button-not-working-correctly-in)).

When the user hits the submit-button I need to know for each row what the `RadioGroup` was set to, in order to then save the values back into a database (been using `SimpleCursorAdapter` so far).

I've looked into `SimpleCursorAdapter.getCount()` and `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` to use a for-loop to traverse the list but still can't figure out how to get a hold of the `RadioGroup` for each list item.

`listView.getAdapter().getItem()` ?

Could you please point me in the right direction? I'm not trying to do anything when the user checks an item or when the state of a button is changed.

Answer (score 3):

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     final int child=listView.getChildCount();
      for(int i=0;i<child;i++) {
        if(listView.childAt(i) instanceof RadioGroup){
         RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)listView.childAt(i);
         int a = rg.getChildCount();
         for(int j=0;j<a;++j) {
            if((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(j).isChecked()==true) {
           System.out.println("RadioButton At "+j+" Is Selected");}
          }
       }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Will try it out as soon as I find the time. Thanks for getting back to me on this.

Answer (score 1):

use a viewHolder in your listview

Model.java

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getModel());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
                TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.label);
  CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.check);
  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
        if(checkbox.isChecked())
        return "is checked";
        else
        return "is not checked";
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        list.add(new Model("Linux"));
        list.add(new Model("Windows7"));
        list.add(new Model("Suse"));
        list.add(new Model("Eclipse"));
        list.add(new Model("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(new Model("Solaris"));
        list.add(new Model("Android"));
        list.add(new Model("iPhone"));
        list.add(new Model("Java"));
        list.add(new Model(".Net"));
        list.add(new Model("PHP"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/my_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

row.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@+id/label"
android:textSize="30sp" >
</TextView>

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/check"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
</CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;
    boolean checkAll_flag = false;
    boolean checkItem_flag = false;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
            } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had faced same problem now what should you need to do it

- just use `getChildCount()` on `ListView`
- Use a loop from for(i=0 upto childoflist)
- Now get child at i th location of listview by using `view=listview.getChildAt(i)`
- Now you must do some thing like
  `radiogroup=view.findViewById(R.id.radiogrp)`
- Now you have all things then u must do `radioButton = (RadioButton)
  rgg.findViewById(selectedId);`

Here i am attaching my code which is in addition to Akhil Jayakumar code of student list

```
///ok is your upload button

ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         final int child=listView.getChildCount();
          for(int i=0;i<child;i++) {
            View rgg=listView.getChildAt(i);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rgg.findViewById(R.id.radio);

    int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    radioButton = (RadioButton) rgg.findViewById(selectedId);

  }
}
});
```

Comment: Will try it out as soon as I find the time. Thanks for getting back to me on this.